# IN_PERSON_SIGNING_HOST_MUST_BE_VALID_USER

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to send a document out for signature for in-person signing. I'm setting the recipients.inPersonSigners array with a signer when doing a POST to /envelopes. I am also sending this envelop on behalf of another user, the user I am sending to is not a DocuSign user but the user who's credentials I am using to make the REST call and the "on behalf of" user are both DocuSign users that I am able to login into DocuSign with. The response I get from DocuSign is "IN_PERSON_SIGNING_HOST_MUST_BE_VALID_USER - The In Person Signing Host must be a valid and active DocuSign user."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are getting correct error, the host for In-Person signing needs to have a valid and active DocuSign Account. HostName and HostEmail should be linked to a user who has a DocuSign account.[image]

JSON will look like below:

```
"recipients": {
      "inPersonSigners": [{
      "routingOrder": 1,
      "recipientId": "1",
      "hostEmail": "validDSuseremail@email.com",
      "hostName": "John Doe",
      "signerName": "Signer Name"
    }]
}
```

Comment: why a downvote, I am giving confirmation that error is correct